# Scapy sr() with custom layers

Tags: python, networking, scapy, bacnet

When using the sr() or srp() function - how does Scapy know that a received packet is an answer to the packet I have sent?

I have written a custom protocol which imitates BACNet. I can send a WHO_IS packet to a BACNet device and the device answers with an I_AM packet, which is correctly disassembled because of layer binding, but the sr function does not recognize it as an answer. How do I make Scapy accept those packets as answers?

Update: 
Thats what my layer classes look like. I think the `answers()` methods look alright, but it still doesn't work. Is there anything I might have misunderstood when implementing the `answers()` methods?
In my understanding `self` refers to the class of the layer itself and `other` is the received packet in question. So, in order to pass the payload on to the next higher layer I pass `other.payload` and call the `answers()` method with the next higher layers class.
The layers are stacked like `Ether/IP/UDP/BVLC/NPDU/APDU`.

```
class BVLC(Packet):

    name = "BVLC"
    fields_desc = [
       # many fields
                   ]

    def post_build(self, pkt, pay):
        if self.length == None:                
            pkt = pkt[0:2] + struct.pack('!H', len(pay)+len(pkt)) + pkt[4:]  
        return pkt+pay

    def answers(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other,BVLC):
            return 0
        else:
            return NPDU.answers(other.payload)


class NPDU(Packet):

    name = "NPDU"
    fields_desc = [ 
        # again, many fields
                   ]

    def answers(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other,NPDU):
            return 0
        else:
            return APDU.answers(other.payload)

class APDU(Packet):

    name = "APDU"
    fields_desc = [
          # many fields and the only relevant field in this case
            ConditionalField(
                ByteEnumField(
                    "serviceChoice", None, APDU_Service_Unconfirmed.revDict()),
                    lambda pkt: pkt.pduType == APDU_Type.CONFIRMED_SERVICE_REQUEST or
                                pkt.pduType == APDU_Type.UNCONFIRMED_SERVICE_REQUEST), 
                   ]

    def answers(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other,APDU):
            return 0
        else:
            if self.serviceChoice == APDU_Service_Unconfirmed.WHO_IS and\
               other.serviceChoice == APDU_Service_Unconfirmed.I_AM:
                return 1
        return 0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scapy `sr` just calls `recv_packet.answers(sent_packet)` for each packet that got sent. 
You will therefore have to implement `def answers()` for your layer, see:

```
def answers(self, other):
    """DEV: true if self is an answer from other"""
    if other.__class__ == self.__class__:
        return self.payload.answers(other.payload)
    return 0
```

Here's an excerpt of the original `TCP` layer:

```
def answers(self, other):
    if not isinstance(other, TCP):
        return 0
    if conf.checkIPsrc:
        if not ((self.sport == other.dport) and
                (self.dport == other.sport)):
            return 0
    if (abs(other.seq-self.ack) > 2+len(other.payload)):
        return 0
    return 1
```

Comment: Thank you, that's the input I needed.

Comment: I have to add something: My layer actually is a stack of three layers. Do I need to add the answers() method in each of these layers? Which layers are significant in order to know whether the received packet is an answer or not?

Comment: Just pass it down the layers until you're certain that the current packet is a response to your packet. Like with TCP. the IP layer implements answers() in a way that it checks src/dst-IP. If it does not match, it pretty early returns False. if it matches it calls sublayer.answers() - in this case TCP.answers() - which checks if sport/dport and seqNr match and returns True. Now you know that IP(src,dst)/TCP(sport,dport,seq) all match and thus it is pretty clear that you received an answer to one of your packets.